# Configure WebStorm Node.js Vagrant Interpreter

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Is there a way to configure Node.js interpreter in Vagrant to WebStorm?

I don't need to run or debug the code via the IDE with remote tools, the only thing I really need is the IDE to be aware of the node version and installed libraries on my Vagrant server in order to have autocompletion.

I consider it should be in `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM` under "Node interpreter" section.

I have Vagrant and Node.js Remote interpreter plugins installed and enabled, set up Vagrant in the IDE, but still WebStorm suggests only to add local interpreter.

If there is a solution for PhpStorm or IntelliJ, would also be appreciated, though I didn't initially plan to pay more for license.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/configure-node-js-remote-interpreter-dialog.html?search=node -- check first sentence for requirements. Also -- *"This menu item is available only when you open the Node.js Interpreters Dialog from the Run/Debug Configuration: Node JS."*

Comment: @LazyOne, that's exactly my question. I don't need a configuration for running or debugging node.js code. I need detection of remote environment for code editor. Is Webstorm capable of this? Or any other IDE? I like to have code completion and code navigation, and yet I'm more comfortable with virtual development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution I came up with.

Install some Node Version Manager on the host machine (could be `nvm` for Unix-like or `nodist` for Windows), download via it and switch to the same version of node.js (or the closest one) as I use in Vagrant and set is as interpreter in the IDE.

Not the way I like it, as I prefer to keep my host machine clean of development environments I work with. But that's the only think that comes to my mind. Would be glad to learn a better solution.

Comment: Ugh, i'm looking to solve the same problem as you.  I'm sad that there does not appear to be a solution to have only the IDE (Webstorm) installed on the host, and have everything else, including NPM, Node etc inside the Vagrant VM :(